# I can't copy my files because "The given path's format is not supported."

Tags: vb.net

So I'm trying to copy the files my user puts into a ListBox, and I appear to have an issue, because on the line where I try to copy the files I get this error:

```
 An unhandled exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in mscorlib.dll Additional information: The given path's format is not supported.
```

After some research I believe it is because I merge strings and stuff, but I'm not sure so I figured I might as well ask here.

If it helps, I verified the listbox items were valid file paths.

Here is my code:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim result As DialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to finish the playlist?", "Finish Playlist- WikiFinder", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo)
    If (result = DialogResult.Yes) Then
        For Each Item In ListBox1.Items
            My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyFile(Item.ToString(), MusicMenu.FolderBrowserDialog2.SelectedPath.ToString() & Item.ToString())
        Next
    Else
    End If
End Sub
```

Keep in mind I've never really worked with listboxes and this is my first time trying the CopyFile method. Can anybody help me?

Comment: the result of `MusicMenu.FolderBrowserDialog2.SelectedPath.ToString() & Item.ToString()` is apparently not valid.  Use `Path.Combine` to create paths, but we have no idea if the listbox items represent valid path segments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Path.Combine method fixed my issue.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim result As DialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to finish the playlist?", "Finish Playlist- WikiFinder", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo)
    If (result = DialogResult.Yes) Then
        For Each Item In ListBox1.Items
            Dim str As String = IO.Path.Combine(MusicMenu.FolderBrowserDialog2.SelectedPath.ToString(), Item.ToString())
            My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyFile(Item.ToString(), str)
        Next
    Else
    End If
End Sub
```

I believe you cannot merge strings when you're writing down paths, and that's what I was doing wrong.

To learn more about Path.Combine: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fyy7a5kt(v=vs.110).aspx